# Show user image next to post

Tags: php, mysql

I've created a table in my database for my users which I want to use together with my table for my private messages on my page. 
I have set my page up so it lists the different meassages from my privat table, which contains both members of the message thread named usr1 and usr2. In my users table I have my username and also a image column.

I've tried the following to pick the image where usr1 matches username in users table, so that I can select the image from the correct user, and then done the same for us2.
Besides trying to match up users.username and privat.usr1 I've tried to use my session name so I said users.username = $_SESSION["navn"] AND privat.usr1=$_SESSION["navn"]
Here's my code:

```
$navnbillede = $_SESSION['navn'];
$query = "SELECT billede FROM users, privat WHERE users.username=privat.usr1";
if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $billede);
while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
$billede = $billede;
}
mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
}
```

This kinda works as I now have the usr1 image shown next to all messages in the thread.I then repeat the code as following

```
  $navnbillede = $besked["usr2"];
  $query = "SELECT billede FROM users, privat WHERE users.username=privat.usr2";
  if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {
  mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
  mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $billede2);
  while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
  $billede2 = $billede;
  }
  mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
  }
```

And then I try to set image like this:

```
if ($_SESSION['navn'] == $besked["usr1"])
{
  $image = $billede;
}
if ($_SESSION['navn'] !== $besked["usr2"])
{
  $image = $billede2;
}
```

And then I run the following:

```
while($besked2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
{
?>
        <li><?php

        echo '<img src="'.$image.'"style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;"/>';

?>
    <a style="text-decoration: none; font-weight: bold; color: white;" href="offentlig.php?id=<?php echo $besked2['usr1']; ?>"><?php echo $besked2['usr1']; ?></a>
        skrev: </br>
        <?php echo $besked2['besked']; ?><br/><br/>
      <?php echo date('m/d/Y H:i:s' ,$besked2['tid']); ?></li>
<?php
}
```

This works absolutely fine, but it never actually displays the right image.

For reference my besked looks like this (and is also functioning):

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, 'select title, usr1, usr2 from privat where id="'.$id.'" and id2="1"');
$besked = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
```

I tried looking into using a **JOIN IN**, but this I couldnt make work either..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a working solution to display the correct image next to each chat message:

```
while($besked2 = mysqli_fetch_array($query2))
    {
      $query = 'SELECT billede FROM users, privat WHERE privat.usr1=users.username AND id2='.$besked2["id2"].'';
      if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $query)) {
      mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
      mysqli_stmt_bind_result($stmt, $billede);
      while (mysqli_stmt_fetch($stmt)) {
      $billede = $billede;
      }
      mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);
      }
    ?>
            <li><?php

            echo '<img src="'.$billede.'"style="max-width:100px;max-height:100px;"/>';

    ?>
```